# ubuntu 18:04 LTS after selecting user an error accrued and cmd open suddenly

Tags: boot, 18.04, login, password

I just upgraded to ubuntu 18.04 LTS waya software update. I'm facing a strange issue. After Boot when is select user then suddenly cmd window opens.

And i cant type password into text box. 
it showing Authentication error without typing password .
even next button is not working.